# How to debug why I'm loosing connection to my Docker container when VPN is up?

Tags: vpn, docker

I'm using Docker 18.06.1-ce on Ubuntu 16, and I have a container exposing 8012 port. When I do

```
curl "http://localhost:8012/"
```

I get response

```
Error: Requested URL / not found
```

But when VPN is up (openfortivpn) after long time waiting I get

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

When I mess my port number, I instantly get error:

```
curl "http://localhost:8011/"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8011: Connection refused
```

How to debug and fix this? Obviously localhost pings, and traceroute to it is one hop.

Comment: Such a failure after "long time wait" could be caused by a stateful firewall timeout somewhere. Tried to do "poor man keepalive" and have ping running infinitely between endpoints? Then, after that time when it usually breaks, check things again, I mean if ping is still running and displays valid connectivity, and if your service still works.

Answer (score 0):

Advice [from here](https://medium.com/@jroyleaz/docker-compose-network-gotcha-69e46c681eb9) helped, I just added

```
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.10.11.1/22
```

to my `docker-compose.yml`. The question on how to debug this remains open.